# CSS selector for child of parent element's sibling

Tags: css

I want to select the next anchor element to the "active" class, in following example I want to select element `<a href="/home?page=2"> 2 </a>` is it possible by class `.active`?

```
<ul class="pagination">
 <li><a href="/home?page=1" class="active"> 1 </a></li>
 <li><a href="/home?page=2"> 2 </a></li>
 <li><a href="/home?page=3"> 3 </a></li>               
</ul>
```

Note : Please note that "active" class is given to the anchor element

Comment: the answer is simple : No with CSS

Comment: @TemaniAfif Though It looks really simple, But I think you are right, Thanks

Answer (score -3):

By using [adjacent sibling selector](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#adjacent-selectors), you can access the next element after a specific element. So in your example, it'd be

```
    .active + li a {
     color: red;
     }
```

And most importantly, move the .active class out into the `<li>` tag like this:

```
<ul class="pagination">
 <li  class="active"><a href="/home?page=1"> 1 </a></li>
 <li><a href="/home?page=2"> 2 </a></li>
 <li><a href="/home?page=3"> 3 </a></li>               
</ul>
```

Comment: read the question carefully and check the HTML

Comment: What am I missing? He wanted to access the next element after the one with .active, didn't he?

Comment: simply read the question again and check his  HTML ... and if not convinced, test your code

Comment: I don't want this to be going back and forth, but I wouldn't be replying back  to if I hadn't reread the question and checked the HTML. Can you please directly tell me what am I missing?

Comment: You are missing nothing .. you are simply wrong ... and i cannot be more direct than the question itself, am not going to write the question again in comment. The question is clearly written and explicit .. so check the HTML strcuture, test your code, as simple as that .... if you still don't see the issue, then read about CSS

Comment: Oh I see, .active should've been moved out into the <li> element. My bad, should've tested my answer before submitting it. I apologize.

Comment: you're still very far...

Comment: Jesus christ, you guys are grilling me over here :D. Well, it's not that I've gave up, but I checked the code snippet in my answer and it's working. so..?

Comment: I see, the guy didn't ask for the .active class to be moved out in the first place.